# SQL - Filtrado en un loop para almacenar resultados

Tags: sql, bucles, while, filtro, cursor

¿Cómo se pueden filtrar varios registros, que deben filtrarse por varios campos que están contenidos en otra tabla? Estoy usando un while (tambien intente con curso pero era un poco mas lento) para ir recorriendo los registros y voy guardando los resultados de las comprobaciones en otra tabla, pero al final tarda mucho en terminar de ejecutarse.

Ejemplo:
Tengo 7 productos con 2 características, color y precio (tabla 1) y tengo a 3 personas que quieren comprar esos productos (tabla 2).

Mi proceso de filtrado sería:
La persona uno quiere una manzana verder y tiene 6 pesos.
La otra persona quiere cualquier producto pero que no sea amarillo, y tiene 15 pesos.
La tercera persona quiere cualquier producto que sea azul y tiene 9 pesos.
etc....

Y en la tercera tabla tengo que guardar los productos que cumplen los requisitos de cada persona.

Dejo un codigo de ejemplo

```
DECLARE @productos AS TABLE (ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,producto VARCHAR(50), color VARCHAR(50), precio INT);
INSERT INTO @productos (producto,color,precio)
VALUES 
('manzana','roja',5)
,('manzana','verde',8)
,('manzana','amarillo',10)
,('platano','amarillo',5)
,('platano','verde',4)
,('aguacate','verde',15)
,('sandia','verde',9);

DECLARE @consumidores AS TABLE (ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,nombre VARCHAR(50), productofavorito VARCHAR(50), colorproducto VARCHAR(50), dinerodisponible INT);
INSERT INTO @consumidores (nombre,productofavorito, colorproducto, dinerodisponible)
VALUES 
('vivian','manzana','verde',6)
,('juan','aguacate','verde',15)
,('celeste','ALL EXCEPT','amarillo',15)
,('german','ALL','roja',5)
,('Jesus','ALL','ALL', 9);

--Tabla para guardar los resultados
DECLARE @consumidorcompras AS TABLE  (nombre VARCHAR(50), productobuscado VARCHAR(50), costoproducto INT, dinerodisponible INT, quierecomprar VARCHAR(5), pudocomprar VARCHAR(5), razonnocompro VARCHAR(50));

--varibles para hacer loop a los consumidores
DECLARE @contadorconsumidores INT = (SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM @consumidores);
DECLARE @contadorconsumidorestemp INT = 1;

WHILE @contadorconsumidorestemp <= @contadorconsumidores
BEGIN
    --varibles para guardar la informacion de forma temporal
    DECLARE @nombre VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @productobuscado VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @colorproducto VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @dinerodisponible INT;
    DECLARE @pudocomprar VARCHAR(5);

    --Llenamos nuestras variables
    --SELECT @nombre = nombre, @productobuscado = productofavorito, @colorproducto = colorproducto, @dinerodisponible = dinerodisponible FROM @consumidores WHERE id = @contadorconsumidorestemp;
    SET @nombre = (SELECT nombre FROM @consumidores WHERE id = @contadorconsumidorestemp);
    SET @productobuscado = (SELECT productofavorito FROM @consumidores WHERE id = @contadorconsumidorestemp);
    SET @colorproducto = (SELECT colorproducto FROM @consumidores WHERE id = @contadorconsumidorestemp);
    SET @dinerodisponible = (SELECT dinerodisponible FROM @consumidores WHERE id = @contadorconsumidorestemp);

    --variables para hacer loop a los productos
    DECLARE @contadorproductos INT = (SELECT COUNT(producto) FROM @productos);
    DECLARE @contadorproductostemp INT = 1;

    WHILE @contadorproductostemp <= @contadorproductos
    BEGIN
        --varibles para guardar la informacion de forma temporal
        DECLARE @producto VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @color VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @precio INT;

        --SELECT @producto = producto, @color = color, @precio = precio FROM @productos WHERE id = @contadorproductostemp;
        SET @producto = (SELECT producto FROM @productos WHERE id = @contadorproductostemp);
        SET @color = (SELECT color FROM @productos WHERE id = @contadorproductostemp);
        SET @precio = (SELECT precio FROM @productos WHERE id = @contadorproductostemp);

        --Aqui determinamos si el consumidor quiere comprar todos los productos y de todos los colores
        DECLARE @AllExceptproduct AS VARCHAR(5) = 'FALSE';
        DECLARE @Allproduct AS VARCHAR(5)  = 'FALSE';
        DECLARE @Allcolor AS VARCHAR(5)  = 'FALSE';
        
        IF @productobuscado = 'ALL EXCEPT'
        BEGIN
            SET @AllExceptproduct = 'TRUE';
        END;

        IF @productobuscado = 'ALL'
        BEGIN
            SET @Allproduct = 'TRUE';
        END;

        IF @colorproducto = 'ALL'
        BEGIN
            SET @Allcolor = 'TRUE';
        END;
        
        --Variables usadas para saber si quiere el producto
        DECLARE @quiereproducto NVARCHAR(5) = 'FALSE';

        IF @AllExceptproduct = 'TRUE' --si eligio comprar todos los productos excepto lo de un color color
        BEGIN
            IF @colorproducto <> @color 
            BEGIN
                SET @quiereproducto = 'TRUE'
            END
        END
        ELSE IF @Allproduct = 'TRUE' --si eligio comprar todos los productos
        BEGIN
            IF @Allcolor = 'FALSE' --si eligio comprar todos los productos de un color especifico
            BEGIN
                IF @colorproducto = @color 
                BEGIN
                    SET @quiereproducto = 'TRUE'
                END
            END
            ELSE --si eligio comprar todos los productos de cualquier color
            BEGIN
                SET @quiereproducto = 'TRUE'
            END
        END
        ELSE --Si el consumidor eligio comprar un producto especifico de un color especifico
        BEGIN
            IF @productobuscado = @producto AND @colorproducto = @color
            BEGIN
                SET @quiereproducto = 'TRUE'
            END
        END

        INSERT INTO @consumidorcompras (nombre,productobuscado,costoproducto,dinerodisponible,quierecomprar,pudocomprar, razonnocompro)
        SELECT @nombre, producto + ' ' + color,@precio, @dinerodisponible,
        CASE WHEN @quiereproducto = 'TRUE' THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
        END,
        CASE WHEN precio <= @dinerodisponible AND @quiereproducto = 'TRUE' THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
        END,
        CASE WHEN @quiereproducto = 'TRUE' AND precio > @dinerodisponible THEN 'NO TIENE DINERO'
        ELSE ''
        END
        FROM @productos
        WHERE id = @contadorproductostemp;
        
        SET @contadorproductostemp = @contadorproductostemp + 1;
    END

    SET @contadorconsumidorestemp = @contadorconsumidorestemp + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM @consumidorcompras ; --aqui mostramos los resultados
```

[Clic para probar el Codigo de Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=789e66ac4e8fdec0e6ccc1b12b665790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo con una query `sql`: hacer un `CROSS JOIN` entre las tablas productos y consumidores y luego utilizar la sentencia `CASE` para calcular las columnas quierecomprar y pudocomprar:

```
SELECT nombre,  
       producto,
       color,
       precio,
       dinerodisponible, 
       CASE WHEN (producto = productofavorito AND color = colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL' AND color = colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL EXCEPT' AND color != colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL' AND colorproducto = 'ALL') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS quierecomprar,
       
       CASE WHEN precio <= dinerodisponible AND ((producto = productofavorito AND color = colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL' AND color = colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL EXCEPT' AND color != colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL' AND colorproducto = 'ALL')) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS pudocomprar
                            
FROM @productos
CROSS JOIN @consumidores
ORDER BY nombre DESC;
```

Si quieres filtrar solo las coincidencias (los productos que quiere comprar cada uno) lo puedes hacer con un `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT nombre,  
       producto,
       color,
       precio,
       dinerodisponible, 
       'TRUE' AS quierecomprar,
       CASE WHEN precio <= dinerodisponible THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS pudocomprar
                            
FROM @productos
INNER JOIN @consumidores ON (producto = productofavorito AND color = colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL' AND color = colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL EXCEPT' AND color != colorproducto)
                            OR (productofavorito = 'ALL' AND colorproducto = 'ALL')
ORDER BY nombre DESC;
```

El resultado de la segunda query sería (con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| nombre | producto | color | precio | dinerodisponible | quierecomprar | pudocomprar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vivian | manzana | verde | 8 | 6 | TRUE | FALSE |
| juan | aguacate | verde | 15 | 15 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Jesus | manzana | roja | 5 | 9 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Jesus | manzana | verde | 8 | 9 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Jesus | manzana | amarillo | 10 | 9 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Jesus | platano | amarillo | 5 | 9 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Jesus | platano | verde | 4 | 9 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Jesus | aguacate | verde | 15 | 9 | TRUE | FALSE |
| Jesus | sandia | verde | 9 | 9 | TRUE | TRUE |
| german | manzana | roja | 5 | 5 | TRUE | TRUE |
| celeste | manzana | roja | 5 | 15 | TRUE | TRUE |
| celeste | manzana | verde | 8 | 15 | TRUE | TRUE |
| celeste | platano | verde | 4 | 15 | TRUE | TRUE |
| celeste | aguacate | verde | 15 | 15 | TRUE | TRUE |
| celeste | sandia | verde | 9 | 15 | TRUE | TRUE |

Comment: muchas gracias, la primera opcion me da exactamente lo que busco, muy agradecido por su ayuda